# zftool create controller not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I add zftool.phar to /usr/local/bin as zftool. I use zf 2.2 in my ubuntu 13.04 machine. I can create project and module at /home/dinuka/workspace using following command.

```
zftool create project test
zftool create module Admin test
```

I try to create a controller inside workspace folder using

```
zftool create controller Home test/module/Admin
```

But it shows following message

```
The path . doesn't contain a ZF2 application. I cannot create a module here.
```

So i move inside to the test directory and try following command.

```
zftool create controller Home Admin
```

But it shows following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory' not found in phar:///usr/local/bin/zftool/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 2
```

All zftool command inside test directory is show above error.

How can i create a controller?

Comment: To create a controller, you must be within a ZF2 app or have it in your PATH, or have the php.ini value `zf2_path`. I created the `create controller` action and I didn't get any problems... I would create an issue on GitHub to get better support.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your project you need to install Zend Framework in it. This is one of the ways to do it if you want your project to contain the Zend Library. 
It is done like this:

```
$ php zftool.phar create project myzendproject
$ cd myzendproject
$ php composer.phar install
```

This will install Zend Framework into your new project

Then you may type:

```
$ cd ..
$ php zftool.phar create module MyModule myzendproject
```

which will create MyModule module into your project, but you have to do this from the parent directory. It won't work if you try from myzendproject$

Good luck!

Comment: how can I thank you? how???? thankyou thankyou thankyou thankyou thankyou thankyou thankyou